How does paging avoid external fragmentation with different page sizes across processes?
It's commonly said that paging has no external fragmentation, only internal fragmentation.
But I've read that some architectures have support for different page sizes. And different processes can use different page sizes.
Wouldn't that lead to external fragmentation?
Suppose there are 3 processes A,B and C. A uses 4KB, B uses 2MB and C uses 1GB page size.
Suppose initially A,B and C pages map to frames in main memory that are contiguous.
If we now decide to deallocate B, the OS has a list of free frames of size 2MB.
How can we bring a new process D in those free frames if lets say Process D uses 4KB page size?
Does the OS use something like buddy system to divide those free frames into smaller frames?

The natural thing is that page sizes are powers of two; two pages of the smallest possible size are allocated together and form one page of twice the size, then two pages of the second smallest size are always allocated together and so on.
If pages are swapped out to an SSD drive, the hardware has a size for erasing segments, typically 128 or 256KB. In that case each such segment is likely allocated to one process to minimise interference between processes.
